# Is it possible for svg tags to use coordinates from a css stylesheet?

Tags: css, svg, coordinates

In order to avoid repetitive coordinates, I would like to be able to get coordinates from a common style.  However, when I tried this, it did not work.  Is this just a syntactic mistake? Is there any way to achieve this?

works:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30">
```

does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="288mm" height="170mm" viewBox="0 0 288 170" version="1.1">
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
rect {x:0;y:0;height:15;width:15; }
.a {fill:#ff0000;}
.b {fill:#00ff00;}
]]>
</style>
<g transform="translate(50,35)">
<rect/>
</g>
<g transform="translate(50,70)">
<rect/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not every attribute in SVG can be used as a style property. Only "presentation attributes" can. You'll have to look at the respective lists in [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/propidx.html) and [SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) and remember that not everything from SVG 2 is implemented yet by all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a use element together with a symbol to provide a common reusable component.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="288mm" height="170mm" viewBox="0 0 288 170" version="1.1">
<symbol id="r">
   <rect width="15" height="15"/>
</symbol>
<g transform="translate(50,35)">
<use href="#r" fill="blue"/>
</g>
<g transform="translate(50,70)">
<use href="#r" fill="red"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: so that's like a subroutine call with no parameters, huh?

Comment: fill="red" or fill="blue" is kind of like a parameter, no?

Comment: Is there any way to change text within the tag ie <text x="1" y="1">change this</text>

Comment: No, because you're not using repetition any more then are you, if you want to draw completely different things you'll have to draw them separately.

Comment: I want to override the contents of the tag, which is just another component, though not an attribute.  A pity.